# Avoid dropping SQL Server table compression settings

Tags: sql-server, dacpac

I normally use DacFx to deploy and update SQL Server DB defined by DacPac. Sometimes I have to tune up by manually modifying the deployed DB by setting up Compression options on a table level. Is there a way to instruct DacFx to not drop manually added compression options when I ask DacFx to apply a newer DacPac?

There are many "Do not Drop" options, but I don't see there anything related to the Compression:
[image]

Comment: Compression is not an object to drop or retain, it's a specific setting on the index (typically the clustered index). What you need should be on the "Ignore" tab (ignore index options).

Comment: Thanks but "Ignore index options" copy/pasting the description: "Specifies whether differences in the index options should be ignored or updated when you publish to a database." cannot distinguish between Data Compression options and any other ones. I need to instruct DacPac deployment to ignore only Data Compression related options but respect all other, how can that be implemented?

Comment: You'd need to pull out custom code then, I'm afraid. This gets complicated fairly quickly. In reality, there are few index options that actually matter in most operational setups, except for compression -- settings like `PAD_INDEX` and `FILLFACTOR` are often poorly understood and misused and should be left to their defaults in almost all cases anyway.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, I appreciate the help, I ended up using your very first advise to use the "ignore index options", please convert your comment to an answer and I will mark it as accepted.